# Openshift - Access tomcat IP address with port 8080 on browser

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, openshift

I have created one tomcat url using these documentation (openshift.com/blogs/free-apache-tomcat-hosting-in-the-cloud-for-java-applications-its-called-openshift). And also I edited server.xml file by inserting the internal IP address. But when I check my internal IP address with port 8080 on browser then it showing webpage is not available. How can I access this IP address with port 8080 available with Tomcat? Please help me.

Thanks & Regards

More Details:

Full details:

This is my domain bit.ly/1qWn28f

I am going to this url through terminal by using ssh username@bit.ly/1qWn28f


$ `rhc app create tomcat diy`


After pushing to git abd SSH into the server, I followed these:


`$ cd app-root/data` 


`$ wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.55/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.55.tar.gz`


`$ tar zxf apache-tomcat-7.0.55.tar.gz`


`$ cd apache-tomcat-7.0.55.tar.gz/conf`

Finding the IP address by running following command:

`$ env | grep IP`

which shows 
OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP = 
Please refer this: dropbox.com/s/yq4lsb5vfu8mplb/address.docx?dl=0

Then I modify the server.xml by inserting following lines:

`<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               address="OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP”
               redirectPort="15443" />`

`<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP">`

`<Host name="bit.ly/1qWn28f"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">`

`<Server port="15005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" address"OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP”>`

`<Connector port="15009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" address="OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP”/>`

`$ cd bin`


`$ sh startup.sh`

How to access through OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add more **specific** information about your problem. It looks like there is a problem with your Tomcat installation. Could you please provide the commands you launched on your machine to install it instead of that link?

Comment: @Numbers Hi Thanks for your comment. I have added more details in my question as per your comment. Hope it helps. Please advise me if you need more details here. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server.xml should look more like this

```
<Connector address="${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP}"
       port="${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT}"
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

However I would suggest going over this article instead for Tomcat applications on OpenShift https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-overview.html.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the URL which you provided me and also this one: [link]https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740